# Spring Boot 2 Thymeleaf Configuration Ignoring 'templates'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm migrating an existing application to Spring 5.0.0.M3 & Spring Boot 2.0.0.M3.  With Spring Boot I'm also importing the Thymeleaf starter.

The application has 2 template folders `mails` and `templates`. If I specify the below configuration for email templates, the `templates` folder is ignored; e.g. I'm getting `FileNotFoundException` for templates in this folder.

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfiguration {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ThymeleafConfiguration.class);

    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf template resolver serving HTML 5 emails")
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        emailTemplateResolver.setPrefix("mails/");
        emailTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        emailTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        emailTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(CharEncoding.UTF_8);
        emailTemplateResolver.setOrder(1);
        return emailTemplateResolver;
    }
}
```

I've tried setting the `setOrder` parameter to 2, 10, etc. which made no difference. If I remove the resolver method, the `templates` folder is recognized, but the `mails` folder isn't.

Any ideas what might be going on?

Answer (score 2):

What I understand is you have *mails* and *templates* sub-folders under the *resources* folder.

You can add *resource* folder as the prefix in your *ClassLoaderTemplateResolver*. Then add *ResourceHandler* for both *mails* and *templates* sub-folders.

**ClassLoaderTemplateResolver**

```
 @Bean
 @Description("Thymeleaf template resolver serving HTML 5 emails")
 public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver() {
     ClassLoaderTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver = new 
     ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
     emailTemplateResolver.setPrefix("resources/");
     emailTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
     emailTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
     emailTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(CharEncoding.UTF_8);
     emailTemplateResolver.setOrder(1);
     return emailTemplateResolver;
}
```

Place your ResourceHandler method in your application class, which your have annotated with *@SpringBootApplication*.

**ResourceHandler**

```
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/mails/**")) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/mails/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/mails/");
    }
    if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/templates/**")) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/templates/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/templates/");
    }
}
```

When you return your view name from any method, it can be like:

```
return "mails/page1";
```

or

```
return "templates/page2";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I guess this would be one way of implementing this.  I'm more interested in why in the `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:2.0.0.M3` the `templates` folder is ignored if `mails` folder is specified.  In the previous version I only needed to specify the `mails` template resolver as per my code above, and the `templates` folder was included by default.  Now if I specifically add the `templates` folder in a new templates resolver, the `mails` folder is ignored, i.e. only one template resolver is injected.  Is this a 2.x 'feature' or a bug?